# Throwing a coin - expected value of tails

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

There are $10$ coins: $8$ of them are fair (equal probability for heads and tails) and for $2$ probability of heads is two times higher than for tails (so $\frac{2}{3}$ for heads). We draw one coin and throw it three times. Let $X$ denote a number of tails - I need to find a $\Bbb EX$. So:

$\Bbb P(X = k) = \Bbb P(X = k| \text{fair coin} ) \cdot \Bbb P(\text{fair coin}) + \Bbb P(X = k| \text{unfair coin} )  \cdot \Bbb P(\text{unfair coin})$

With

$\Bbb P(X = k| \text{fair coin} )={3 \choose k} (\frac{1}{2})^k(\frac{1}{2})^{3-k}$

$\Bbb P(\text{fair coin}) = \frac{8}{10} $

$\Bbb P(X = k| \text{unfair coin} )={3 \choose k} (\frac{1}{3})^k(\frac{2}{3})^{3-k} $

$\Bbb P(\text{unfair coin})= \frac{2}{10} $

So

$\Bbb P(X = k) = {3 \choose k} (\frac{1}{2})^k(\frac{1}{2})^{3-k} \cdot \frac{4}{5} + {3 \choose k} (\frac{1}{3})^k(\frac{2}{3})^{3-k}\cdot \frac{1 }{5} $

And then obviously $\Bbb EX = \sum\limits_{i=0}^3 i\cdot \Bbb P(X=i)$

Am I correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me. A simpler way would be just compute probability of seeing a tails from a randomly chosen coin from this collection and multiply it by three (since you are just interested in the expected value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that the expectation of a binomial is $\mu=np$ thus you have

$$E(X)=\frac{8}{10}\times 3 \times \frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{10}\times 3 \times \frac{1}{3}=\frac{14}{10}$$

---

this easy method works as you pmf is a mixture of two pmf's

$$p_X(x)=0.8p_{X_1}(x)+0.2p_{X_2}(x)$$

Comment: thanks! it works the same for variance right?

Comment: @thesecond: Yes.. but it depends what  you mean with "works the same for variance"...try it! it will be useful

Comment: @thesecond : here it is! to calculate the variance, first derive the second moment. So first observe that in a binomial $\text{Bin}(n,p)$ you have $E(X)=np$,$V(X)=npq$ and thus $E(X^2)=npq+n^2p^2$



thus

$$E(X^2)=0.8\left(3\cdot\frac{1}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{2} +9\cdot\frac{1}{4}  \right)+0.2\left( 3\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}+9\cdot\frac{1}{9}\right)$$

then

$$V(X)=E(X^2)-E^2(X)$$

Comment: thanks a lot!!!